# How can I deserialize a multilevel JavaScript object to an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, post, deserialization, json-deserialization

**EDIT**: there are one conceptual error and one technical error on the problem definition so this question should better be closed instead of sanitized. When I have time to redefine the problem I'll post it again. **Please help voting to close because of unspecific.**

There are lots of info and questions about serializing complex HTML forms to its corresponding JavaScript object (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407771/1670956)).

Here is a sample of that process: having this form

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="scalar" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="array[0]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="array[1]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="array[2]" value="3">
    <input type="text" name="object[subscalar]" value="1">
</form>
```

And getting from it this javascript object

```js
{
  "scalar": 1,
  "array": [1, 2, 3],
  "object": {
    "subscalar": 1
  }
}
```

But how can I do the inverse job?

Our goal is to perform a native POST targeting a separate browser window. We have a complex JavaScript object and we were sending through an AJAX POST, so we were using the object directly as jQuery.ajax data parameter. But now we need to create a real form in the DOM containing the inputs and values with all that brackets syntax, and then natively submit it targeting a specific frame.

jQuery usage is optional. Already existing method, library, etc is preferable against a custom snuppet. This isn't about not being able to code it, it's about not being sure we need to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you have a form from which you fetch values?

Comment: Your structure doesnt make sense. Why do you need a name like "dream[as]..." generated dynamically??

Comment: @Rajesh no, I have a JS object and I need to generate a form which the browser can send producing the same POST it produces when I send that object through XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: One option is to create a in memory form and then manually submit it. Other option is you can create a serialized string. Not sure how arrays will be represented in them though

Comment: Sorry guys, there are one conceptual errors and one technical error on the problem definition so I am closing this now until I have time to redefine the problem. Please help voting to close for unspecific. Thank you all for the time invested here.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseform(elem,parent=""){
    this.html="";
    this.parent=parent;
    if(typeof elem=="Array"){
        var counter=0;
        elem.forEach(function(a){
            this.html+=new parseform(a,this.parent+"["+counter+"]").html;
            counter++;
        });
    }
    if(typeof elem=="String"){
        this.html+="<input name='"this.parent+"["+elem+"]' />";
    }
    //object in progress
    if(typeof elem=="Object"){
        for (var key in elem) { 
            if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
                this.html += new parseform(elem[key],this.parent="["+key+"]").html;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
 code=new parseform(yourjsondecoded).html;
```

I know you dont want code, but i dont think that theres an api for something so specific

Comment: Sorry guys, there are one conceptual errors and one technical error on the problem definition so I am closing this now until I have time to redefine the problem. Please help voting to close for unspecific. Thank you all for the time invested here.